# Jquery calling PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I'm attempting to call a PHP file from Jquery. My website shows "hi" once my button is clicked so I know the click() function is being called but I don't get a response from my test.php file. Furthermore, my php file loads without error when called independent from this script.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submitButton').click(function(){
    //var theName = $( "#name" ).val();
    //var theID = $( "#transaction" ).val();
    alert("hi");
           $.ajax({
              url: "test.php?name=Charlie&transID=1234",
              type:'get',
              success: function(data){
                  alert(data);
              }
           });
        }
    )
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
    <input id="name" type="text" size="20" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
    <input id="transaction" type="hidden" name="transactionID" value="12345">
    <input id="submitButton" type="submit" name="submit" value="Call PHP">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$name=$_GET['name'];
$id=$_GET['transID'];

echo("Thank you $name for transaction #:$id");
?>
```

Thanks,
Craig

Comment: Hi Craig, Could you please add test.php code too. So i can give to proper help.

Comment: Watch the network tab, what happens?

Comment: Is `test.php` in the same folder as the HTML file?

Comment: Either the OP ran off to school, work, other..., is busy trying to fix it themselves, or is expecting a magical answer; the latter is not going to happen. We won't setup a script just for you. You need to respond to the above comments, that's IF you're around.

Comment: Put the complete path in url and use datatype for response

Comment: @Fred-ii- Working on other projects. I don't get paid to sit around on SO all day. Full code has been uploaded.

Comment: Also, all files (html, js, php) are in the same directory for simplicity

Comment: After watching the network tab in Chrome as @chris85 suggested I saw an "error 401" being thrown. This site is a sandbox and hosted in a password protected directory. After providing a username/pw I have accessed both files (html, php) continually with no problem. Apparently access between the html to the php  (via jquery) requires some additional authentication? I've removed the password protected directory for now. I'll need to do more research.

Comment: Buy Stack stocks, like I did, you'll make a killing from helping people ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to turn off my password protected directory on my webserver which hosted these files in order to successfully call the php file using jquery. With the password protected directory turned on the jquery threw a Error 401 which I was able to catch by viewing the Network tab within Chrome. Still unsure why I was able to provide username/password once and continually access the files via my browser while my script was denied access during the same session.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the ajax call to test.php page isn't working right.  Change your ajax call code to:

```
 $.ajax({
          url: "test.php?name=Charlie&transID=1234",
          type:'get',
          success: function(data){
              alert(data);
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
              alert('Status:' + textStatus + '\r\n\r\n' + errorThrown);
          }
       });
```

This will show any errors occurring during the ajax call.

Comment: I appreciate this approach as its very methodical. For some reason it does not catch error 401 issue.